# Graph Algorithm : Similar to TSP

Tags: graph-algorithm

I want to solve a problem similar to the TSP( Travelling Salesman Problem).
I have N ( N > 0, N < 20 ) nodes and i must visit all nodes.
The cost between nodes are equal.
I can visit a node unlimited times.
I want to find more than one path and the cost have not restriction.
Tell me some effective algorithms about this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I posted a solution that works in `N*2^N`, much better than the naive in `N!`, so with `N<20`, it becomes totally feasible.  It outputs one optimal path.  Could you elaborate on what you have in mind when you write "more than one path"? Do you want to enumerate all optimal paths perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works with a weighted graph.

First, the naive solution, enumerating.

It works in `O(n!)` because there are `(n-1)!` Hamiltonian paths, and you need O(n) to check each one.

There is better algorithm, with dynamic programming in `O(n*2^n)`

Define the state as the following:  for `x` a node, and `S` a set of nodes containing `x`:

`w[S][x]` = the weight of the shortest path that start at node `x`, and goes through all the node in the set `S`, and then finishes at `0`.

Note that `0` does not necessarily belongs to `S`.

`S = {x}` is the basic case: `w[S][x] = weight(w,0)`

Then the recursion formula:

If `S` is larger than, `{x}`, Iterate over the possible next step `y`

```
w[S][x] = min(weight(x,y) + w[S\x][y] for all y in S\x)
```

This algorithm will output just one optimal path.